# ImageMenuItem and textview

Tags: pygtk

I have menu on my form and gtktextview:
I create imageitemmenu:

```
   self.file_new = gtk.ImageMenuItem(gtk.STOCK_NEW, agr)
   key,mod = gtk.accelerator_parse("N")
   self.file_new.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod,gtk.ACCEL_VISIBLE)
```

But when i press n in textview at this time triggered file_new menu
activate... How can i resolve it? And how can i make hot keys for
example CTRL + W + S?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it!

```
key,mod = gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>n")
```